# Replacing an ECU

Tags: toyota, electronic-control-module, speedometer, instrument-cluster, avensis

i changed the ECU on a Toyota Avensis 2009, it turns on and everything is fine, but the instrument cluster isn't working at all...

It was working perfectly before i replace the ecu?

Any clue why this might be happening?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Did you replace it with a used one? If so, might be defective also.

Comment: Check your connections and fuses.

Answer (score 1):

Is the ECU the exact same model year as the car?  ECU's can be very picky about which model year they will work with.  Often times the software is changed every model year, even sometimes mid-model year.